# EF Core: Should I explicitly add new related entity to its table instead of adding it into the collection in the entity that it is related to?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following 3 entity types:

```
public sealed class Book
{
    public ICollection<BorrowLog> BorrowLogs { get; private set; }
    public int AvailableBooks { get; private set; }

    public void DeductFromAvailable(int value)
    {
        AvailableBooks -= value;
    }
    // Other properties and methods.
}

public sealed class MemberAccount
{
    public ICollection<BorrowLog> BorrowLogs { get; private set; }
    //Other properties

    public MemberAccount()
    {
        BorrowLogs = new List<BorrowLog>();
    }

    public void BorrowABook(Book book)
    {
        var log = new BorrowLog(book, this);
        BorrowLogs.Add(log);
        book.DeductFromAvailable(1);
    }
}

// MemberAccount and Book entities have one-to-many relationship with BorrowLog
    public sealed class BorrowLog
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; private set; }
        public Book BorrowedBook { get; private set; }
        public MemberAccount BorrowedMember { get; private set; }
        public DateTimeOffset BorrowedDate { get; private set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? ReturnedDate { get; private set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? WrittenOffDate { get; private set; }
        public bool WasReturned { get; private set; }
        public bool WasWrittenoff { get; private set; }
    
        public BorrowLog()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            BorrowedDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            ReturnedDate = null;
            WrittenOffDate = null;
            WasReturned = false;
            WasWrittenoff = false;
        }
    
        public BorrowLog(Book book, MemberAccount member)
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            BorrowedBook = book;
            BorrowedMember = member;
            BorrowedDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            ReturnedDate = null;
            WrittenOffDate = null;
            WasReturned = false;
            WasWrittenoff = false;
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new `BorrowLog` object within the `BorrowABook()` method of `MemberAccount` class and add to its `BorrowLogs` navigation property.

And my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TestBorrowAsync()
{
    var user = await _context.Members
                            .Include(x => x.BorrowLogs)
                            .FirstAsync();

    var book = await _context.Books.FirstAsync();

    //BorrowABook method is called and the new log is supposed to be created.
    user.BorrowABook(book);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    var log = await _context.BorrowLogs.FirstAsync();
    return Ok(log);
}
```

In this approach, when I call `await _context.saveChangesAsync();` following exception is thrown:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The
> database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually
> affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since
> entities were loaded.

Therefore, I changed the code to explicitly update the `BorrowLogs` table.
In the MemberAccount class:

```
//BorrowABook method now returns newly created log instead of inserting it to the BorrowLogs navigation property.
public BorrowLog BorrowABook(Book book)
{
    book.DeductFromAvailable(1);
    return new BorrowLog(book, this);
}
```

And the controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TestBorrowAsync()
{
    var user = await _context.Members
                            .Include(x => x.BorrowLogs)
                            .FirstAsync();

    var book = await _context.Books.FirstAsync();
    var newLog = user.BorrowABook(book);

    //Explicitly inserting the new log to the table.
    await _context.BorrowLogs.AddAsync(newLog);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    var log = await _context.BorrowLogs.FirstAsync();
    return Ok(log);
}
```

And then, the application works as expected. My question is should I explicitly add new entities to the tables even though they are related entities.

Comment: It's usually not required to explicit add a new entity to the corresponding `DbSet<>`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data#adding-a-related-entity. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which generates the error you get.

Comment: @Progman I edited the question and tried to make it both clear and short as much as possible without mentioning all other non-relevant properties.